# python unexpected EOF when running os.system()

Tags: python, linux, shell, command

**Task:**
I'm trying to run a system command in python. The command is a webhook for IFTTT that send a notification to my phone. I followed this article [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-your-phone-from-any-script-6b70e34748f6).

I tried running it via bash but didn't have much luck with the argument formatting (I don't know bash, at all). So instead I am using python. Here is my code.

```
import os
command = """curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"I'm frustrated"}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/notify_phone/with/key/<my_key>"""
os.system(command)
```

Notice how my "value1" for json is "I'm frustrated". The single quote in I'm is not appreciated by the computer, and I cannot figure out why. I'm presented with the following error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I've also tried the following commands and I'm greeted with the same error, so I'm really confused.

```
command = """curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"I\'m frustrated"}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/notify_phone/with/key/<my_key>"""
```

and

```
command = """curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"I\\'m frustrated"}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/notify_phone/with/key/<my_key>"""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's better to build commands using [**`subprocess`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) so they get escaped/quoted correctly.

Comment: I can never remember the rules, it's trial and error: Perhaps `I\'m`. As I say, use `subprocess`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried running it via bash but didn't have much luck with the argument formatting (I don't know bash, at all). So instead I am using python.

Ah, but you're using [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) which runs in a subshell, so you're still using a shell, likely bash or an equivalent.  So you haven't avoided the same escaping challenge.

> Task: I'm trying to run a system command in python.

Looking at your question, I think you're *actual* task is to make a web request.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"I'm frustrated"}' https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/notify_phone/with/key/<my_key>
```

Okay, so you're making an HTTP POST of Json data.  If you're comfortable in python, why call out to a different executable to make an HTTP request?
[requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) is the most common way of doing this in python.

Starting from the example in that link, something like

```
r = requests.post('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/notify_phone/with/key/<my_key>', data={'value1':'I\'m frustrated'})
```

> `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

I believe you'll get this for free when you pass an object as data.  But it's certainly possible to set it explicitly with `requests`.

For what it's worth, the escaping problem you're hitting is a quirk of bash syntax: `\'` does not escape a single quote in a single quoted string.  Think of `'` in bash like a "toggle"; one `'` disables special characters, another `'` re-enables them.  Since `\` would be a special character in the phrase `'\''`, it is not a valid expression.

Peter Wood says,

> It's better to build commands using subprocess so they get escaped/quoted correctly.

The reason [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) works so much better than `os.system` is because you get to specify the arguments as separate values in the call, so you don't need to escape anything for the shell itself.  In fact, you don't
need a shell to invoke `curl`.

```
subprocess.run(["curl", "-X", "POST", ..., ... ], capture_output=True)
```

Your POST data would still have to be formatted as valid json:

`... '-d', '{"value1":"I\'m frustrated"}'`

Python has sane, standard quote esacping for `'`.

```
>>> print('I\'m working')
I'm working
```

If you really wanted to do this in bash shells, it is possible through a number of mechanisms.  Here's one:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value1":"I'\''m frustrated"}' http://httpbin.org/post
```

But to reiterate, just use python's requests.  It will handle encoding your Json data properly, and if you should ever care about the *return* of the web request, handling that in requests will be *much, much*  easeer than it would dealing with curl's output.